# Fetching Simple JSON String Array using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I want to fetch JSON string array from server using Retrofit.
The JSON array is like this.

```
["A","B","C"]
```

Here is the code I made .

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url="http://proverbs-app.antjan.us";

    RestAdapter restAdapter;        
    restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(url)
    .build(); 

    Service service=restAdapter.create(Service.class);
    service.get(new Callback<List<String>>(){


        @Override

        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

        @Override
        public void success(List<String> arg0, Response arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
         });    
}
```

}

Here is the Service.class

```
public interface Service {
@GET("/")
public void get(Callback<List<String>> callback);
```

}

It shows only "Error" Toast.

Am I something wrong with my codes.
Please help me to fix it.
I'm a beginner.
So,please answer me in detail because I don't know much about it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of error are you facing?

Comment: post your logcat error..we cannot predict without logcat error

Comment: Please do not change the question when you face a new problem. Other users might run into the original issue, and answers provided below are now no longer related to the question.

Comment: @LinLin Enable logging for Retrofit and check the log for possible error `new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify relative path for URL in the interface.

```
@GET("/")
public void get(Callback<List<String>> callback);
```

Comment: Yes , sir .
I tested by changing it but still show the same logcat output I've shown.

Comment: public interface Service {
 @GET("/")
 public void get(Callback<List<String>> callback);

}

Comment: @LinLin Since you are getting `NoClassDefFoundError` try kevin's solution and also add thes [proguard-square-retrofit.pro](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-retrofit.pro) lines in your Proguard file.

Comment: @b1izzardNow I can fix crashing.
But I got an "Error" Toast while running app.
Can u check where I was wrong,sir?
I accidentally edited the question.I'm so sorry ,sir.

Comment: @LinLin Had you enabled retrofit logging, as I mentioned in the above comment?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing Gson. Add this line to your `dependencies` block in `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

Comment: Sir,I'm now using Eclipse .
I added Retrofit.jar to build path.

Comment: Then you should download the Gson jar and add that one as well. You can get it here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.3.1%7Cjar

Comment: Yes , sir .It fix app crashing.
But showing a toast "Error".
Can you check my codes ,sir?

Comment: You would have to paste the content of the RetroFit error before anyone would be able to see what is wrong. If you can't find the problem yourself, you should create a new question, because it is not directly related to this one.

Comment: I'm sorry sir.I'm a newcomer and I didn't notice that.
Can you also check what am I wrong right now , Sir?